# How to create Oauth2 with graphql

Tags: node.js, oauth-2.0, graphql, feathersjs

I am using feathers server and I want to implement Oauth2 authentification with facebook or github strategy or whatever. But I also would like to use with graphql

But I dont know how to implement with graphql I'm using https://github.com/feathersjs/feathers-authentication-oauth2 it works as a API if I send GET request on callback url it works correctly I get token but I'd like do this with graphql as for example in LOCAL or LDAP strategy

```
const authentication = feathers()

authentication.configure(hooks())
        .configure(rest(base).superagent(superagent))
        .configure(auth({ storage: localStorage }));


RootMutation: {
    signInLocal(root, {email, password}, context){
        return authentication.authenticate({
            strategy: 'local',
            email: email,
            password: password
        }, context).then(data=>{
            // console.log(data)
            return data
        })
    },
    signInLdap(root, {username, password}, context){
        return authentication.authenticate({
            strategy: 'ldap',
            username: username,
            password: password
        }, context).then(data=>{
            // console.log(data)
            return data
        })
    }
}
```

I tried

```
RootQuery: {        
    signInGithub(root, data, context){
        return authentication.authenticate({
            strategy: 'github',
        }, context).then(data=>{
            console.log(data)
            return data
        })
    }
},
```

But I got error

```
feathers-authentication:passport:authenticate 'github' authentication redirecting to https://github.com/login/oauth/authorize?response_type=code&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A3000%2Fauth%2Fgithub
%2Fcallback&scope=user&client_id=0b786a43497059d2a28b 302 +3ms

feathers-authentication:middleware:failure-redirect Redirecting to https://github.com/login/oauth/authorize?response_type=code&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A3000%2Fauth%2Fgithub%2Fcallback&scope=
user&client_id=0b786a43497059d2a28b after failed authentication. +7ms

Error: Unexpected end of JSON input
```

Thanks for any help